# How to mark a scope as required in Facebook OAuth2?

Tags: facebook, permissions, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to mark a scope such as `publish_stream` as required in Facebook OAuth2?
Currently a user can skip the permission and that results in a non working app in my example.

Comment: What do you mean by "mark a scope"?

Comment: Currently the scope "publish_stream" can be skipped by a user, but to make my application work, this permission is required. I'm looking for a way to remove the SKIP button from the OAuth2 dialog of Facebook.

Comment: That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** you cant do that, in fact facebook asks to check for the extended permissions before performing any related action.

You can any time check for the permissions a user has granted with the API- `/me/permissions`. Check out- [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "require" extended permissions such as `publish_stream` as far as I know. Facebook has some docs about how to handle those cases where the user only gave some permissions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#handling

Quote:

> If a person declines the login dialog have a clear and upfront
>   explanation about why you are requesting each permission. Then let
>   them click or tap to opt back in to the permission request dialog. Do
>   not immediately redirect them into a permission request dialog without
>   an explanation.
>
> For cases where someone has granted some permissions but not others,
>   only prompt for missing permissions at the point at which they are
>   needed. For example, if your app contains functionality which creates
>   an event on behalf of a person, only prompt for create_event
>   permission whenever they choose to add the event to Facebook.
>
> Unless the permissions you are requesting in the login dialog are
>   critical to the functionality of your app and a feature doesn't work
>   without them, let people continue using your app without the
>   permissions.